# How to create a new Entry model in Craft 3?

Tags: plugin-development, entry, entrymodel, saveentry

I want to create a new entry for a section named 'drinks'(having section id= 6). The namespace of the file having this code is `namespace putyourlightson\userguide\controllers;`.I copied this code from StackExchange. My first line is getting an error(`Class 'Craft\EntryModel' not found`).

```
$entry = new \Craft\EntryModel();

$attributes = [
  'section'   => $yourSectionId,
  'entryType' => $yourEntryTypeId,
  'field1'    => 'foo',
  'field2'    => 'bar'
];

$entry->getContent()->setAttributes($attributes);

craft()->entries()->saveEntry($entry);
```

How should you import it?[image]

Comment: Do you mean add a new section model, or a new entry type maybe? (Because line one in your code is creating a new entry model)
If you're just wondering how to save an entry as it looks like above, [check the docs here](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/craft-entriesservice.html#method-saveentry)

Comment: ok I was not clear ...1st line is not working for me.my question should have been how do you import EntryModel

Comment: The EntryModel class is under the `Craft` namespace. If your plugin isn't under the `Craft` namespace (back in Craft 2 most plugins _were_ as the examples were all like that) you'll need to `use` it at the top of the plugin/class where your code is. so `use Craft\EntryModel;` should do it. Or namespace the EntryModel right there `$entry = new Craft\EntryModel();`

Comment: but still it is showing ERROR -Class 'Craft\EntryModel' not found

Comment: I tried to use $entry = new \Craft\EntryModel(); as well,it is also not working

Comment: Ahh, you're trying to use Craft 2 code in Craft 3. You've just looked at the wrong docs. Try [this link](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html#method-saveelement) for the Craft 3 version. (Most things have dropped "Model" from their names so you want `new Entry();`)

Answer (score 4):

Just so there's an answer here. OP was using Craft 2 code in a Craft 3 environment.

The code should be something like this in Craft 3:

```php
$entry = new Entry();
$entry->sectionId = $yourSectionId;
$entry->typeId = $yourEntryTypeId;
$entry->authorId = $yourAuthorId;
$entry->enabled = true;
$entry->title = "Foo";
$entry->setFieldValues([
    'field1' => "Foo",
    'field2' => "Bar",
]);
$success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
if (!$success) {
    Craft::error('Couldn’t save the entry "'.$entry->title.'"', __METHOD__);
}
```

Comment: still not solving my problem.First line is showing error.How can you import the Entry class correctly?

Comment: I have editeed my qn for better clarity

Comment: Hi, sorry I just saw this again. I think my previous comment on how to import (`use`) PHP classes in your code covers that. If you'd like to read more on that, [the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) are worth a look. You could do something like `use craft\elements\Entry as MySpecificUseOfAnEntry;` and then when you want to new up that class do `$entry = new MySpecificUseOfAnEntry();` and the code above, with those changes, will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Either use

```
use craft\elements\Entry;
$entry = new Entry();
```

OR

```
$entry = new \craft\elements\Entry();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download and see guest-entries plugin code to correctly see how to save an entry from a plugin.